# Error management

Tags: java, error-handling

I use spring boot in a rest architecture.
I'm a newbee with error management.

My code have this structure

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void processPayment() throws CreditCardPaymentException{
    List<Payment> payments = paymentRepository.findByDateLessThanEqualAndPaymentModeAndStatus(LocalDate.now(), PaymentModeEnum.CREDITCARD, StatusEnum.STANDBY);
    processCreditCardPayment(payments);
}

private void processCreditCardPayment(List<Payment> payments) throws ProcessPaymentException{
    PaymentGatewayConfig paymentGateway = new PaymentGatewayConfig();
    String crypt_type = "7";
    for (Payment payment : payments) {
        chargeMemberCreditCard(payment, crypt_type, paymentGateway);
    }
}

private ResolverReceipt chargeMemberCreditCard(Payment payment, String crypt_type, PaymentGatewayConfig paymentGateway) throws ProcessPaymentException {

    try {
        if (resreceipt != null) {

            //information about customer we have sent are returned
            ResolveData resdata = resreceipt.getResolveData();
            //todo check auth code
            if (Boolean.valueOf(resreceipt.getComplete()) && !Boolean.valueOf(resreceipt.getTimedOut())) {
                //if (resreceipt != null && resreceipt.getResponseCode() != null && Integer.getInteger(resreceipt.getResponseCode()) < 50) {
                payment.setStatus(StatusEnum.COMPLETE);
            } else {
                payment.setStatus(StatusEnum.FAIL);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ProcessPaymentException();
        log.error("chargeMemberCreditCard -  payment: " + payment.getPaymentId(), e);
    }

}
```

If there is an error in a payment, I want to pass to the next one.
If there are many error at the end, I just want to know there are err who happen.

No sure if it's the way to go and if this code will do that.

Comment: Try/catch with a List of failures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accumulate your failed `Payments` or `Exceptions` in `processCreditCardPayment`

```
private void processCreditCardPayment(List<Payment> payments) throws ProcessPaymentException{
PaymentGatewayConfig paymentGateway = new PaymentGatewayConfig();
String crypt_type = "7";
List<Payment> failedPayments = new ArrayList<Payments>();
for (Payment payment : payments) { 
    try {
        chargeMemberCreditCard(payment, crypt_type, paymentGateway);
    } catch (ProcessPaymentException ppe) {
        filedPayments.add(payment);
        // or you can accumulate excetions instead of Payments
    }
}
// create some higher level exception with failed Payent collection and throw it, or log it.
```

Comment: if i understand, in ProcessPaymentException, i must have a list of payment?

Comment: Nope, in every iteration of cycle you already have payment.
You just catch exception in every iteration that can be thrown in `chargeMemberCreditCard`. When you catch exception you add payment that cause the exception in filedPayments list. ProcessPaymentException can contains no special data at all.